# Google Play Console "Invalid file format" cant upload my apk

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, apk, google-play-console

i have a apk (working on phone) but i cant upload it to Google Play. Console.Built by Unity. What should i do?

I‘m getting
“Invalid file format”

Comment: Is it a non-development build signed with a release keystore?

Comment: i think apk is not using anymore..

Comment: Yeah, if it's a new app you need to make an App Bundle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to upload Android App Bundle (.aab) file.

Because now you are only allowed to upload Android App Bundle (.aab) file instead of (.apk).

> Important: From August 2021, new apps are required to publish with the
> Android App Bundle on Google Play.

https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle